Two indentatinons in one image for two different captions
So my collage require that my work should have one upper cation for an Image and another one at the bottom just for the source of the image.
That being said , it also requires that the first caption has to be centered and the source caption has to be justified.
here is the slice of the code with preambule, a print and the example:
The image that i ought to make:

The code that I am using, notice that the packages are required for other parts of the text:
\documentclass[12pt,a4]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} %Pacote para acentuação
\usepackage[portuguese,brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage[lmargin=3cm,tmargin=3cm,rmargin=2cm,bmargin=2cm]{geometry} %Formato que lembra a ABNT
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} %Ajusta o texto que vem de outras fontes
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,amssymb,dsfont,mathtools,blindtext} %pacotes matemáticos
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{caption}%sub da imagem
\usepackage{subcaption}%sub do sub da imagem
\usepackage{mathptmx} % times New Romam
\usepackage{changepage} % para ajustar posiocionamento do texto
\usepackage{setspace} % aqui dá pra usar singlespacing, doublespacing , onehalfspacing
\onehalfspacing % 1,5 linhas de espaço entre palavras
\usepackage[rm,tiny]{titlesec}% fazendo com que as seções sejam do mesmo tamanho do resto do texto
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat} %sem hífem no texto
\usepackage[labelfont=bf]{caption} % Numeração das figuras em negrito

\usepackage{xcolor} % para cor da fonte
\usepackage{ragged2e}% para usar \justify{ text } fora do contexto geral

\usepackage{indentfirst}%indentar o primeiro paragrafo de uma folha
\setlength\parindent{1.5cm}

%---- configuração do sumário justificado
\usepackage{tocloft}
%\setlength{\cftpartindent}{0em}
%\setlength{\cftchapindent}{0em}
%\setlength{\cftsecindent}{0em}
\setlength{\cftsubsecindent}{0em}
\setlength{\cftsubsubsecindent}{0em}

\renewcommand{\cftsecleader}{\cftdotfill{\cftdotsep}} % fazendo a primeira seeção ter linhas

\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{0pt} % pacote toclof , remove o espaço entre seção

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\l@section}% <cmd>
  {\addvspace{0em \@plus\p@}}% <search>
  {}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
  
%---- configuração do sumário justificado


%---- Citação ABNT
\usepackage[alf,abnt-repeated-title-omit=yes,abnt-emphasize=bf,abnt-etal-list=0]{abntex2cite} 
\citebrackets()


%citação direta margeado
\newenvironment{cited}
{\vspace{12pt}\hfill\begin{minipage}{12cm}}
{\end{minipage}\vspace{12pt}}

%---- Citação ABNT

%------------------configuração de pageamento
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % para cabeçalho de pagina e cor
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{} % Limpa cabeçalhos e rodapés
\rhead{\textcolor{gray}{\thepage}} %deixa a cor cinza ;r- right e h-head
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % Remove a linha do cabeçalho

\usepackage{afterpage}%apagar só uma página

%------------------configuração de pageamento
\begin{document}


\begin{figure}[H]
\caption{Imagem}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{imagem.pdf}
\raggedleft
\caption*{\fontsize{10}{12}fonte do menino.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}

What it gives:

I am using overleaf.

You don't need or want \caption to write text in a figure.  \caption is used increment the figure counter and send a copy to the list of figures.  All you need is a \par or blank line.after the image.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Note that you should really clean your preamble up. It is going to bite you when it is least convenient.

Besides \centering, one can center images one at a time using \centerline{...}, \hfil ... \par or \makebox[\linewidth]{...}.  The caption centers itself.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{showframe}% alignment tool

\setlength\parindent{1.5cm}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]% friends don't let friends use H
\centering
\caption{Imagem}
\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image}

\parbox{\linewidth}{\fontsize{10}{12}fonte do menino.}% un-center text
\end{figure}

\end{document}


Hey john! it seams that it worked out even with all my predefined preamble, i greatly give thanks for your answer.

You should define a \source command.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\captionsetup[figure]{position=top}

\newcommand{\source}[2][0pt]{%
  % #1 is an optional indentation
  % #2 is the text
  \par\addvspace{1ex}% or whatever you prefer
  % we want to override a possible `\centering`
  \hspace*{#1}%
  \parbox[t]{\dimeval{\textwidth-#1}}{\footnotesize #2}\par
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\caption{The caption to the figure}

\includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image}

\source{Source of the image}

\end{figure}

\end{document}


The same, but with
\source[0.05\textwidth]{Source of the image}



Hey egreg! i tried to use your answer but the one that john gave me also worked and i think it was kind of simple so i am using his for this problem, but i thank you immensely for the time you expended on the answer.

sed 's/should/could/' :).

@cfr I consciously used “should”.
